# Deploy front-end angular app at with json-server Cloud9

Tags: angularjs, json, deployment, cloud9-ide

I'm new to web development and just finished Angular course at Coursera.

Everything was OK to my course project app until I have decided to deploy it at Cloud9. So the app doesn't have back-end and takes data from a simple db.json file which I was running on my computer with the json-server at localhost:3000.

I have cloned my git repo to the Cloud9, installed all dependencies and thought that the procedure with json-server will be the same and it will serve json data at the server, but it's looking that I was wrong.

I think I missed something and asking for explanation of my problem.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to develop on Cloud9, you'll need to make sure you use `process.env.IP` instead of localhost and `process.env.PORT` (or port 8080) instead of 3000.

That being said, Cloud9 is not a hosting solution. If you use it as such, your account will be deactivated. Consider something like Heroku for deployment.